# Object.defineProperty on a prototype prevents JSON.stringify from serializing it

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm using TypeScript to define some classes and when I create a property, it generates the equivalent to `Class1` in the following plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NXUo7zjJZaUuyv54TD9i?p=preview

```
var Class1 = function () {
  this._name = "test1";
}

Object.defineProperty(Class1.prototype, "Name", {
  get: function() { return this._name; },
  set: function(value) { this._name = value; },
  enumerable: true
});

JSON.stringify(new Class1()); // Will be "{"_name":"test1"}"
```

When serializing, it doesn't output the property I just defined.

`instance2` and `instance3` behave as I'd expect by serializing the defined property. (see the plunkr output).

My actual question is: Is this normal?

If so, how do I work around it in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can define a [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) method on your prototype to customize how instances are serialized.

```
Class1.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    return {
        Name: this.Name
    };
};
JSON.stringify(new Class1()); // Will be '{"Name":"test1"}'
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because I ended up implementing toJSON myself. I already had a map of private members to public properties because I was using it to map some JSON from my API to my TypeScript classes. In the toJson methods, I simply use that map to create a new object with all properties with the inverted names. I'll blog about it soon.

Answer (score 17):

If you like to push it forward, give a try to decorators proposal for TypeScript:

According to this proposal (https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators):

A decorator is:

- an expression
- that evaluates to a function
- that takes the target, name, and property descriptor as arguments
- and optionally returns a property descriptor to install on the target object

It goes like this (high level view):

Client code:

```
@serializable()
class Person {

    constructor(name: string) {
      this._name = name;
    }

    private _name: string;

    @serialize()
    get name() {
      return this._name;
    }

    @serialize('Language')
    get lang() {
      return 'JavaScript';
    }
}
```

Infrastructure:

```
const serialized = new WeakMap();

export function serializable(name?: string) {
    return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
        target.prototype.toJSON = function () {
            const map = serialized.get(target.prototype);
            const props = Object.keys(map);
            return props.reduce((previous, key) => {
                previous[map[key]] = this[key];
                return previous;
            }, {});
        }

    }
}

export function serialize(name?: string) {
    return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
        let map = serialized.get(target);
        if (!map) {
            map = {};
            serialized.set(target, map);
        }

        map[propertyKey] = name || propertyKey;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I extracted this sample decorator into a repository at https://github.com/awerlang/es-decorators

Comment: Very interesting! But not a viable solution in the short term for this project. Thanks!

Comment: yep, you're right, but I find it very promising and hope to use it in production very soon

Comment: I know it's a bit late to ask since TypeScript has been updated, but in my case, the WeakMap is always empty even if `serialize` is called. Any idea ?

Comment: @Jacks perhaps you were retrieving using a class as key, instead of a class' prototype? I updated my answer with a working implementation, so take a look.

Comment: @AndréWerlang Thank you very much for your update. Yes, I was indeed in the first trying to retrieve values by passing the class and not its prototype. But for the verification, I was trying to print the whole WeakMap which was not possible because keys where not enumerable (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164054/typescript-using-decorators-for-custom-json-serialization)). Thanks for clarifying this post years after :)

Comment: Hi, I love this solution, but my Typescript is giving me [an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446480/typescript-decorator-reports-unable-to-resolve-signature-of-class-decorator-whe) when I try to use `@serialize` property decorator, or `@serializable` class decorator: "Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when used as an expression ". I think I'm using [*TypeScript* decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) , which seem to be different than the [decorators](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators) you linked

Comment: For me , if I 1) clarified my functions' return types include `ClassDecorator` (for `serializable`) and `PropertyDecorator` (for `serialize`),  2) explicitly cast to `<ClassDecorator>` and `<PropertyDecorator>` to satisfy the return type; that error message goes away! So I can use the rest of your code as-is, I didn't mean to confuse the variations on the way a decorator function can be written; (i.e. TypeScript class decorators can accept the constructor function!) I prefer your syntax here... thanks again!

Comment: How exactly did you do that @TheRedPea? Care to share a gist?

Comment: @Apidcloud , something like this (note I removed chunks, this code won't run, but I added arrows to show the use of `ClassDecorator` and `PropertyDecorator` https://gist.github.com/theredpea/c4e6c7923467db57b6afd867a0e1ecc1

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is by design.

As defined in ECMA, only *own enumerable properties* are serialized (`stringify()` is defined in terms of `Object.keys()`, among others).

Property accessors are defined on prototypes, both in TypeScript and ES6.

And answering your last question, that is the most eficient way to perform this operation.

Beside that, only a) defining an toJSON() to each object part of the serialization, or b) passing a replacer function/array as 2nd argument to JSON.stringify().

Whitelist properties from prototype:

```
JSON.stringify(instance, Object.keys(instance.constructor.prototype))
```

Comment: I went with the toJSON approach. I'll blog about it soon.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, it won't serialize properties defined on prototype.

I know it's not ideal, but another option is to do this:

```
class Class1 {
    private _name = "test1";

    Name: string; // do this to make the compiler happy

    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "Name", {
            get: function() { return this._name; },
            set: function(value) { this._name = value; },
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
}
```

Defining the property on the instance will serialize the property.

Comment: I had considered this, but I want a solution that uses TypeScript itself.

Comment: @ChristianDroulers yeah, I wouldn't use this solution either :)... adding a toJSON method is a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Put something here hopefully can help others.
What I have do for fix JSON.stringify not serialize properties defined on prototype

```
var newObject = $.extend(false, {}, orginalObj);
```

then I notice newObject have instance properties instead of prototype properties.
I'm use typescript and get accessor.