# How to avoid hard coded this? in Decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, ecmascript-2016

I have read ["How to implement a typescript decorator?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator) and multiple sources but there is something that i have nor been able to do with decorators.

```
class FooBar {
    public foo(arg): void { 
        console.log(this);
        this.bar(arg);
    }
    private bar(arg) : void { 
        console.log(this, "bar", arg);
    }
}
```

If we invoke the function `foo`:

```
var foobar = new FooBar();
foobar.foo("test");
```

The object `FooBar` is logged in the console by `console.log(this);` in `foo`

The string `"FooBar {foo: function, bar: function} bar test"` is logged in the console by `console.log(this, "bar", arg);` in `bar`.

Now let's use a decorator:

```
function log(target: Function, key: string, value: any) {
    return {
        value: (...args: any[]) => {
            var a = args.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join();
            var result = value.value.apply(this, args); // How to avoid hard coded this?
            var r = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(`Call: ${key}(${a}) => ${r}`);
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

We use the same function but decorated:

```
class FooBar {
    @log
    public foo(arg): void { 
        console.log(this);
        this.bar(arg);
    }
    @log
    private bar(arg) : void { 
        console.log(this, "bar", arg);
    }
}
```

And we invoke `foo` as we did before:

```
var foobarFoo = new FooBar();
foobarFooBar.foo("test");
```

The object`Window` is logged in the console by `console.log(this);` in `foo`

And `bar` is never invoked by `foo` because `this.bar(arg);` causes `Uncaught TypeError: this.bar is not a function`.

The problem is the hardcoded `this` inside the `log` decorator:

```
value.value.apply(this, args);
```

How can I conserve the original `this` value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't use an arrow function. Use a function expression:

```
function log(target: Object, key: string, value: any) {
    return {
        value: function(...args: any[]) {
            var a = args.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join();
            var result = value.value.apply(this, args);
            var r = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(`Call: ${key}(${a}) => ${r}`);
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

That way it will use the function's `this` context instead of the value of `this` when log is called.

---

By the way, I would recommend editing the descriptor/value parameter and return that instead of overwriting it by returning a new descriptor. That way you keep the properties currently in the descriptor and won't overwrite what another decorator might have done to the descriptor:

```
function log(target: Object, key: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    var originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
        var a = args.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join();
        var result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        var r = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(`Call: ${key}(${a}) => ${r}`);
        return result;
    };

    return descriptor;
}
```

[More details in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837695/188246) - See the "Bad vs Good" example under "Example - Without Arguments > Notes"

Comment: Thanks for the answer I didn't notice that I was using an arrow function.

Comment: @OweRReLoaDeD yeah, very easy thing to miss. I didn't notice until I popped it in playground and saw the javascript doing `_this`

Comment: The OP's code appears to be from my blog post - https://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/typescript-1-5-get-the-decorators-in/ - I'll update it! :)

Comment: I also had this issue son a blog post updated contetn at http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript

Comment: Nice example! one nitpick: seems the type of `target` should be `Object` not `Function`, since it's the prototype of the Class.

Comment: @JannyHou yeah it should be. I had just copied and pasted from the question without looking at it in detail. I'll update it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use

```
var self = this;
```

in order to preserve the 'this' at that specific point. Then, just use `self` at the later point where you would have wanted that particular `this`

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer but when using a decorator I don't have control over an specific point