# How are decorators (annotations) compiled in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

In Angular 2, I can create a component, like this:

```
import {Component, Template} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
@View({
  inline: "<div>Hello my name is {{name}}</div>"
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Max'
  }
  sayMyName() {
    console.log('My name is', this.name)
  }
}
```

(source: http://blog.ionic.io/angular-2-series-components/)

This is then compiled into regular ES5.

My question is in 2 parts:

1. These decorators are specific to Angular. How are they defined?
2. How do I define my own decorators?

Comment: See http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript. This question also seems quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465214/access-meta-annotation-inside-class-typescript/34466523

Comment: That's a good blog post there.

Answer (score 24):

In fact, you should call "annotations" decorators since it's slighty different ;-) They allow to decorate objects. This blog post can give some more hints here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html.

So decorators aren't something specific to Angular. There is a proposal for ES7 and they are also supported by the TypeScript language itself. This can be used in conjonction with the [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/jonathandturner/decorators/blob/master/specs/metadata.md) library (it's contained into the `angular2-polyfills.js` file) to set and get metadata for elements.

- **Class decorator**

  ```
  export function MyClassDecorator(value: string) {
    return function (target: Function) {
      Reflect.defineMetadata("MyClassDecorator", value, target);
    }
  }

  @Component({ ... })
  @MyClassDecorator("my metadata")
  export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
      let decoratorValue: string
        = Reflect.getMetadata("MyClassDecorator", this.constructor);
    }
  }
  ```
- **Function decorator**

  ```
  export function log(target: Object,
                  propertyKey: string,
                  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    var originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
      console.log("The method args are: " + JSON.stringify(args));
      var result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
      console.log("The return value is: " + result);
      return result;
    };

    return descriptor;
  }

  export class AppComponent {
    constructor() { }

    @MyMethodDecorator
    getMessage() {
      return 'test';
    }
  }
  ```
- **Parameter decorator**

  ```
  export function MyParameterDecorator(param1) {
    return function(target: any, methodKey: string | symbol,
                    parameterIndex: number) {
      (...)
    };
  }
  ```
- **Class property decorator**

  ```
  export function MyPropertyDecorator(target: any,
          propertyKey: string | symbol) {
    (...)
  }
  ```

So in general a decorator corresponds to a function. If there is no need to return a wrapping one if you don't use parameter. If you want to use parameters for the decorator you need an additional function to get parameters and return the actualy decorator:

```
// In the case of a parameter decorator
// myMethod(@MyDecoratorWithoutParameter someParam) { ... }
export function MyDecoratorWithoutParameter(target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol, parameterIndex: number) {
  console.log('decorator called');
}

// myMethod(@MyDecoratorWithParameter('test') someParam) { ... }
export function MyDecoratorWithParameter(param1) {
  // param1 contains 'test'
  return function(target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol,
                  parameterIndex: number) {
    console.log('decorator called');
  };
}
```

Here is a plunkr corresponding to my samples: https://plnkr.co/edit/0VBthTEuIAsHJjn1WaAX?p=preview.

Here are links that could give you more details with TypeScript:

- [How to implement a typescript decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator)
- [How to avoid hard coded this? in Decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329832/how-to-avoid-hard-coded-this-in-decorators#answer-30330602)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/04/30/announcing-typescript-1-5-beta.aspx

Hope it helps you,
Thierry