# what does decorators in angular2 do in components?

Tags: angular, decorator

What is the use of the decorators in angular2 ? What does it do?
like to annotate and modify classes and properties at design time.
This sounds pretty much like what annotations do right?
Could you explain this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides meta information for components, directives, pipes, and for dependency injection.

They can be used by tools for linting and auto-completion and other design tools.

Build tools will generate code (or HTML/CSS) from them.

See also [How are decorators (annotations) compiled in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921476/how-are-decorators-annotations-compiled-in-typescript)