# What is the difference between annotation and decorator?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am confused when to use term annotation and when to use decorator ?

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'tabs',
      template: `
      `
    })
    export class Tabs {

    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A decorator corresponds to a function that is called on the class whereas annotations are "only" metadata set on the class using the Reflect Metadata library.

With TypeScript and ES7, `@Something` is a decorator. In the context of Angular2, decorators like `@Component`, `@Injectable`, ... define metadata for the decorated element using the `Reflect.defineMetadata` method.

This question could interest you to find out what a decorator actually is:

- [How are decorators (annotations) compiled in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921476/how-are-decorators-annotations-compiled-in-typescript/34925432)

Comment: Can you help me to sort it out this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613097/no-provider-for-response-in-angular-2-even-thought-i-have-added-providers-in-com

Answer (score 2):

Traceur gives us `annotations`. TypeScript gives us `decorators`. But Angular 2 supports both.

Annotations create an "annotations" array. 
whereas Decorators are functions that receive the decorated object and can make any changes to it they like.

As angular use TypeScript instead of atScript so it is using decorators. There are basically four kind of decorators
are there which are

- Class decorators, e.g. @Component and @NgModule
- Property decorators for properties inside classes, e.g. @Input and @Output
- Method decorators for methods inside classes, e.g. @HostListener
- Parameter decorators for parameters inside class constructors, e.g. @Inject

For more in depth you can refer

- https://toddmotto.com/angular-decorators
- http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/annotations-vs-decorators/

Answer (score 2):

Code from a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-detail',
  ......
})
```

**@Component**: is a decorator

**app-customer-detail**: is an annotation

> Decorators provide a way to add both [annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) and
> meta-programming syntax for class declarations and members. Decorators
> are a stage 2 proposal for JavaScript and are available as an
> experimental feature of TypeScript.

There are different types of decorators:

- Class Decorator : `@Component`
- Method Decorator: `@HostListener`
- Property Decorator: `@Input/@Output`
- Parameter Decorator: `@Inject`