# No provider for Response in angular 2 even thought i have added providers in component?

Tags: typescript, angular

Error: This is the error I am getting even thought I have added provider to mine component.I am unable to get what's the mine error for. here are mine all file 
app.component.ts, app.component.html, carservice.ts.
I am unable to solve.

```
 EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
    ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Response!
    ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
    error: DI Exception
    platform-browser.umd.js:962 Error: DI Exception
        at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (core.umd.js:3776)
        at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (core.umd.js:4307)
        at new NoProviderError (core.umd.js:4342)
        at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.umd.js:5794)
        at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.umd.js:5822)
        at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.umd.js:5785)
        at ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.umd.js:5594)
        at DebugAppView._View_IntegratedWorkshop_Host0.createInternal (IntegratedWorkshop_Host.template.js:29)
        at DebugAppView.AppView.create (core.umd.js:9862)
        at DebugAppView.create (core.umd.js:10054)
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {InputText,DataTable,Button,Dialog,Column,Header,Footer,Dropdown,SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

import {CarService} from './cars/carservice';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [InputText,DataTable,Button,Dialog,Column,Header,Footer,Dropdown],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS,CarService]
})
export class AppComponent{
  selectedCity: string;
  cars: SelectItem[];

    constructor(private carService: CarService) { 
         this.cars = [];
         this.cars.push({label: "label", value: "value"});
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsMedium().then(cars => this.cars = cars);
    }
}
```

app.component.html :

```
<div >

   <p-dropdown [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
   <p>Selected City: {{selectedCity||'none'}}</p>

</div>
```

carservice.ts :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class CarService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getCarsMedium() {
        return this.http.get('app/resources/data/cars-medium.json')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <Car[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }
}
export interface Car {
   label;
   value;
}
```

main.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

cars-medium.json

```
{
    "data":[
       {"label":"Mercedez", "value":"Mercedez"},
       {"label":"BMW", "value":"BMW"},
       {"label":"Lam", "value":"Lam"},
       {"label":"Ista", "value":"Ista"},
       {"label":"Ferrari", "value":"Ferrari"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where are you using the Response?

Comment: form json object data.

Comment: I can't see it in your code

Comment: sorry i forgot to add Now you can see.

Comment: try to change import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http'; to main.ts and set bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS])

Comment: @ Kayo Lima : I try with adding provider in main.ts but still facing same issue :(

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/4MjEzWrD7IhOCKko8KGP?p=preview. Do you somewhere in your code: `providers: [ Response ]` (or equivalent)?

Answer (score 0):

`Response` depends on `ResponseOptions` and `ResponseOptions` is not designed in a way it can be injected easily. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/%40angular/http/src/base_response_options.ts#L57

If you are injecting `Response` somewhere then you're probably doing something that is not supposed to work this way.

Comment: That means Where i am putting my .json file(ie response ) that's not the right place which is defined in my project ?

Comment: Your code doesn't show where or how you are using `Response` therefore it's hard to tell if it's the right place. I'm not sure what you mean by "Where i am putting my .json". How is the json file related to the error message and `Response`?

Comment: Perhaps, My project structure is made that way so i cant put my own .json file in my project there may be some specific place.What's your thought ?

Comment: The error message says "No provider for Response". I have no idea how you related this error message to the position where you place your json file. You import `Response` why don't you provide information about how and where you use it?

Comment: I used this response to mine dropdown box as shown using primeng component

Comment: Previously I was trying with primeng component without json object at that time it was working absolutely fine when i added services then i got this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide the Response, it's a reference generated by the Http itself. In the early days of alpha version I faced the same error and solved it using this line: `constructor(@Inject(Http) http : Http)`.
In the constructor of your CarService just add @Inject and tell us if it solves your problem.

carservice.ts **becomes**:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class CarService {

    constructor(@Inject(Http) http : Http) {}

    getCarsMedium() {
        return this.http.get('app/resources/data/cars-medium.json')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <Car[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }
}
export interface Car {
   label;
   value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i got the solution 
I just added 
var jsonFiles = 'src/app/**/*.json';
    gulp.src(jsonFiles).pipe(gulp.dest('build/app')).pipe(gulp.dest(env.deployPath + '/app'));

to my gulp-typescript.js and it works

Comment: Are you using gulp-typescript to dev or just to production? It's strange, beacuse the error itself doesn't have much connection with project structure.