# what is the difference between annotations and decorators in angular2

Tags: angular

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: 'Hello World!'
})
class MyComponent {}
```

> what are the differences between annotations and decorators in angular2/4?
>   how we can use the annotations and why?
>   when we use decorators and why?
>   what is tha image annotation
>   Example: how i can do tag annotation for apicture in angular2/4
>   if any one have  example please share it to me

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between annotation and decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317705/what-is-the-difference-between-annotation-and-decorator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorators are a proposed standard for ECMAScript 2016 by Yehuda Katz, to annotate and modify classes and properties at design time. This sounds pretty much like what annotations do right? Well… sort of. Let’s take a look at what a decorator looks like:

```
// A simple decorator
@decoratorExpression
class MyClass { }
```

`@Component` is an annotation that tells Angular, that the class, which the annotation is attached to, is a component.

`@Component` is something we need to import from the Angular framework like this:

```
import { 
  ComponentMetadata as Component,
} from '@angular/core';
```

For more you can look into this [Difference](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html).

Comment: I have Image Annotation in angualr 1.x ,I want to use it or convertit  into Angular2(Typescript). Any URl r suggetions Please.