# Typescript Decorators and Arrow Function

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I'm trying to implement a Typescript method decorator as follows.

```
function dataMethod(name: string, options: any) {        
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {        

    }
}
```

And its used as below.

```
class HelloWidgetExtesion {         
    @dataMethod("getData", {})
    public getData(name: any, cb: any) {
        cb(null, "");
    }
}
```

But I'm trying to figure out how to use decorators with Arrow function implementation as below.

```
class HelloWidgetExtesion {         
    @dataMethod("getData", {})
    public getData = (name: any, cb: any) => {
       cb(null, "Greetings from Loopback!");
    }
}
```

But the above implementation shows the following error when compiling.

> error TS2322: Type '(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor:
>   TypedPropertyDescriptor) => void' is not assignable to type
>   '(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void'.

[Demo of the issues.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20dataMethod(name%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20any)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3A%20TypedPropertyDescriptor%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20HelloWidgetExtesion%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%40dataMethod(%22getData%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getData%20%3D%20(name%3A%20any%2C%20cb%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cb(null%2C%20%22Greetings%20from%20Loopback!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the last case field `getData` is considered by compiler as property (not pure method). 
This means that the `descriptor` arguments would not be passed in compiled javascript file.

All that you need it is modify your decorator and make `descriptor` field optional. Consider this example:

```
function dataMethod(name: string, options: any) {        
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {        

    }
}
```

I have modified your example [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20dataMethod(name%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20any)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3F%3A%20TypedPropertyDescriptor%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20HelloWidgetExtesion%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%40dataMethod(%22getData%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getData(name%3A%20any%2C%20cb%3A%20any)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cb(null%2C%20%22%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20HelloWidgetExtesion2%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%40dataMethod(%22getData%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getData%20%3D%20(name%3A%20any%2C%20cb%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cb(null%2C%20%22Greetings%20from%20Loopback!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Good Luck

### **Related Resources** (thanks for it @David Sherret)

1. [Decorators signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837695/4891253)

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds :) This is correct. An arrow function on a class is not a method—it's a property—and so the implementation of the decorator needs to be compatible with both the method and property decorator function signatures as shown in Oleg's example. ([See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29775830/188246) for the property and method decorator signatures)

Comment: Thank you Oleg Dokuka and David Sherret!

Comment: How do I configure it for a .js file?