# TypeScript custom event listener

Tags: typescript

I think I'm missing something quite substantial from the understanding here, so perhaps a little explanation, too, would be incredibly helpful.

I have a class, as such:

```
class Entity {
    protected pos: number = [0,0];

    ...

    public setPos(x: number, y: number) {
        this.pos = [x, y];
    }
}
```

and would like something like

```
class EntityPositionListener {
    //do stuff when an Entity position changes
}
```

I also have descendants of the `Entity` class.  As such, any time any descendent of `Entity` or `Entity` itself changes the `pos` variable (in a given instance), I would like to know about it so that I can update the position on the map, as well as capture the instance so I could theoretically do other things to that instance.

I've noticed that Firefox has that `Object.watch()` command and I found a "cross-browser" solution someone had posted in another question--to no avail--and I've tried "wrapping" the `Entity` class in a post-init phase, but the latter just ends up overwriting the `Entity` class or creates a infinite loop, so I'm obviously missing the point somewhere.  If wrapping is the answer, how do I do this in TypeScript?  The JS version created a loop or didn't work.

```
//This created an infinite loop in runtime, but more importantly overwrote the Entity class
function EntityListener(name) {
    cout(name);
}
var oldEntity = Entity;
function Entity(name) {
    if (typeof EntityListener === "function") {
        EntityListener(name);
    }

    oldEntity(name);
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to listen to several things on a given class--such as in the game update loop--this particular case just used for demonstration.  I've found countless links, many of which are JS and not explicitly TypeScript, so I would really like a TypeScript solution and some explanation as to what's going on.  I am just fundamentally not understanding how to go about this.

**EDIT**

If this is a better version of the question, maybe more simply, how do I listen for `Entity.setPos()` to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) will be most likely [dropped](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe). [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) is only supported in Gecko, so don't use it in your code unless you target only Firefox.

This means that you have to write your own event emitting. You can use TypeScript getters and setters if you like them:

```
class Entity {
    private entitityListener:EntityPositionListener;
    private _pos:number[] = [];

    get pos():number[] {
        return this._pos;
    }
    set pos(value:number[]) {            
        this._pos = value;

        if (this.entitityListener) {
            this.entitityListener.reportEvent('pos', value);
        }
    }
}

class SuperEntity extends Entity {

}

let superEntity = new SuperEntity();
superEntity.pos = [1,2]; // this will call 'this.entitityListener.reportEvent()' and you don't need superEntity.setPos([1,2]);
```

which transpiles to:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var Entity = (function () {
    function Entity() {
        this._pos = [];
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Entity.prototype, "pos", {
        get: function () {
            return this._pos;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this._pos = value;
            if (this.entitityListener) {
                this.entitityListener.reportEvent('pos', value);
            }
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Entity;
})();
var SuperEntity = (function (_super) {
    __extends(SuperEntity, _super);
    function SuperEntity() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return SuperEntity;
})(Entity);
var superEntity = new SuperEntity();
superEntity.pos = [1, 2];
```

You can use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute) to define getters and setters and this means that you can define setter to contain a call to a `EntityListener` method.

Comment: Is it possible to change this code such that the EntityPositionListener listens for any time Entity [set] is called without modifying the setter function?  My reservation with this solution is that I'll have to go back and modify functions to activate functionality in the listener, rather than have a listener do stuff with whatever instance of the class called that function; or is this not possible?

Comment: I have updated the answer. To be honest, I think that you will find a way how to do what you want. However, it will backfire sooner or later IMO. I used to do some crazy stuff so I'm talking from my own experience. :-)

Comment: Would you be OK with TypeScript decorators? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator may be a reasonable solution of your problem.

Comment: No idea what those are, but they look interesting prima facie.  Regardless, I spent a bit playing with your code and I think I finally understand the methodology here and your warning otherwise and find it much more practical than I had originally thought.  Thanks a ton for the help! :)

Comment: Those decorators are awesome!  That's pretty much exactly what I could have hoped for ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Best is to use the `subscribe` approach, so you can automatically support any number of event listeners on the object, and not just one. And use a strongly-typed event, for type safety.

Several libraries can do such a thing today. Here's an implementation via [sub-events](https://github.com/vitaly-t/sub-events):

```
import {SubEvent} from 'sub-events';

type PosChanged = {newPos: number[], oldPos: number[]};

class Entity {

   // strongly-typed event:
   readonly onPosChanged: SubEvent<PosChanged> = new SubEvent();

   private _pos: number[] = [];

   get pos(): number[] {
       return this._pos;
   }

   set pos(newPos: number[]) {
       // can add verification here, if it actually changed;
       const oldPos = this._pos;
       this._pos = newPos;
       this.onPosChanged.emit({newPos, oldPos});
   }
}
```

Any derived class then can subscribe to the `pos` change:

```
const e = new Entity();

e.onPosChanged.subscribe(data => {
    // data is strongly-typed

    console.log(data); //-> { newPos: [ 1, 2, 3 ], oldPos: [] }
});

e.pos = [1, 2, 3]; // this will trigger the event
```