# angular + restangular + typescript decorators error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, decorator, restangular

I'm using:

- angular 1.4
- restangular for models
- typescript as the language

This is my code:

```
  function plain(){
    return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {
      var originalMethod = descriptor.value; // save a reference to the original method
      descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
        var result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        return result.then(function stripRestangularAttributes(response){
          return response.plain();
        });
      };
      return descriptor;
    };
  }

  export class XYZ {
    @plain
    public getSomethingBySomething(data: Data): restangular.IPromise<any> {
      if (!entityKey && !period) {
        return null;
      }
      return this.restangularElement.all("route1/route2").post(data);
    }
  }
```

I get following error:

> > error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
> >       Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

It is thrown on the `@plain` line.

Some info:

- Restangular methods, `.post(data)` in this example, return promises

I want to:

- use a typescript method decorator to chain a single element in the promise chain. The chain element is a *thenable* - something that will call `.plain()` on restangular results, so that I would just use `@plain` on any method and all results will get *`plain()`-ed automagically*.
- in other words, when restangular returns a promise (as it always does), I want to chain following to each method that has `@plain` decorator attached: `.then(function stripRestangularAttributes(response){
        return response.plain();
      })`

Unfortunately, I can't get what is typescript complaining about in above example.

PS I've been reading [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837695/769384) as my TS decorators guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method decorator shouldn't return a function, according to the spec:

```
declare type MethodDecorator = <T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void;
```

Try this instead:

```
function plain(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    var originalMethod = descriptor.value; // save a reference to the original method
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
        var result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        return result.then(function stripRestangularAttributes(response){
            return response.plain();
        });
    };
    return descriptor;
};
```

Comment: you are absolutely right! This solves my problem completely :) I just had some issues with tslint, but, it was way easier than above.