# How to pass an instance variable into typescript decorator arguments?

Tags: typescript, decorator

[How to implement a typescript decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator) is a good example about how to use decorator in typescript.

Considering the below case,

```
class MyClass {
    @enumerable(false)
    get prop() {
        return true;
    }

    @property({required: true}) //here pass constant is no issue
    public startDateString:string;

    @property({afterDate: this.startDateString}) //how to pass startDateString here?
    public endDateString:string;
}

function enumerable(isEnumerable: boolean) {
    return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {
        descriptor.enumerable = isEnumerable;
        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

I tried everything but it seems I have no way to pass `startDateString` into decorator argument. `startDateString` could be a variable, a function and a reference.

Comment: This might be possible depending on _how_ and _when_ you need to use the passed in value. I get it that you need to pass the... errrr... _instance value_ of `startDateString` to the decorator applied to `endDateString`, but what are you planning to _do_ with it in the decorator? Depending on circumstances, it _is_ possible to get an instance member through a decorator.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

Decorators get called when the class is declared and at this time there is no instance to pass into the decorator.

For example, with this code:

```
class MyClass {
    startDateString: string;
    @property({ afterDate: this.startDateString })
    endDateString: string;
}
let myClass = new MyClass();
```

1. `MyClass` is declared.
2. The decorators are run on `MyClass`. There is no instance that exists to pass in at this point and `this` in the decorator argument refers to the global object—not an instance.
3. `new MyClass()` is called and the instance is created. Decorators aren't called on this step. That already happened.

Take a look at the compiled JavaScript for reference:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    // -- 1 --
    function MyClass() {
    }
    // -- 2 --
    __decorate([
        // see here... `this` is equal to the global object
        property({ afterDate: this.startDateString })
    ], MyClass.prototype, "endDateString", void 0);
    return MyClass;
})();
// -- 3 --
var myClass = new MyClass();
```

Note that using `this.startDateString` doesn't throw a compile error here because `this` is typed as `any`.

So what is trying to be done here by passing in an instance property doesn't make sense and isn't possible.

What you could do is make `startDateString` static then pass it in like so: `@property({ afterDate: MyClass.startDateString })`.

Comment: Thanks. But in my case, it cannot be static to be a class variable. It has to be an instance variable.

Comment: @new2cpp one thing you could do is pass in a string or a function that is passed an instance of the class and returns the property value. Something like `{ afterDate: "startDateString" }` or `{afterDate: (instance: MyClass) => instance.startDate }`. You could then use this information later once you have an instance of the class to get the value out of the property. It's a hacky solution that's a great way to confuse everyone looking at the code though.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access to a object property from a attribute definition.

Decorator is called when the property is defined.

You could use getter or setter to get control when access to the property.