# Typescript decorator is not setting property value

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to learn about decorators but am not sure why the code below doesn't return what I'm expecting...

I want to decorate a class with a string value, which I then assign to a property of the same name within that class.

**Person.ts**

```
@course({
    id: 'rainbow'
})
export class Person {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public returnNames() {
        console.log('Firstname: '+this.firstName+'. Lastname: '+this.lastName+'. ID: '+this.id);
    }
}

export function course(options: { id: string }) {
    console.log(options.id);
    return (target :any) => {
        target.id = options.id;
    }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { Person } from "./Person";

class Startup {
    public static main() {
        var test = new Person('Matt','OConnor');
        test.returnNames();
    }
}

Startup.main();
```

The output from running this is...

```
$ node main.js
rainbow
Firstname: Matt. Lastname: OConnor. ID: undefined
```

Why is the Id undefined and not 'Rainbow'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756294/how-to-pass-an-instance-variable-into-typescript-decorator-arguments

Comment: In short, `target` is the class `Person`, not instance of `Person`.