# Why is `this` undefined when passing a Function into Metadata and how to fix it?

Tags: typescript, reflect-metadata

I want to create an abstraction with the help of Typescript decorators and [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata). But when I invoke the function I pass into the metadata, `this` is undefined:

```js
import "reflect-metadata";

const METHODS = "__methods__";
const Method = (obj: object) => {
  return function MethodDecorator(
    target: object,
    methodName: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) {
    const metadata = Reflect.getMetadata(METHODS, obj);

    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      METHODS,
      { ...metadata, [methodName]: descriptor.value },
      obj
    );
  };
};

const someObject: object = new Object();
class Main {
  private num = 42;

  constructor(other: Other) {
    other.init(someObject);
  }

  @Method(someObject)
  myMethod() {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log(this.num); // this is undefined (how can I fix it?)
  }
}

class Other {
  private methods: Record<string, Function> = {};

  init(obj: object) {
    this.methods = Reflect.getMetadata(METHODS, obj);
  }

  trigger(methodName: string) {
    this.methods[methodName]();
  }
}

const other = new Other();
new Main(other);
other.trigger("myMethod");
```

The output of the code snippet above is

```
hello
undefined
```

#### Why is `this` undefined and how can I fix it?

---

You can try it yourself by cloning [this](https://github.com/flolu/reflection-this-undefined) sample repo and running

```
yarn install
yarn start
```

Comment: did you tried it with `.bind()`?   `myMethod() { ... }.bind(this)`

Comment: @Ifaruki I thought about that. But I am not sure how this can be done in my example, because I don't have a reference to `this` inside `MethodDecorator`. 

Maybe with the help of `target`?

Comment: Hmm ot you just put `this.num =4;` inside your constructor?

Comment: @Ifaruki It's just an example. In my real use case there are values assigned at runtime

Comment: I don't totally understand you question but I do know this:
You can call a function with a custom this like: `myfunc.call(this)`
OR, a solution that I think is more likely, is that ES6 arrow functions actually modify the `this` keyword from what we're used to. Try using a normal function instead of the arrow function.

Comment: btw, I'm talking about the `Method` arrow function on line 4

Comment: @VirxEC The arrow function is what @Terry has also proposed, but this doesn't seem to work. The `.call(this)` seems like a good idea. However for it to work the `this` has to be passed to the `Other` class which is similar to the answer by @jdaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save the value of `this` by passing it to `other.init`, as below, and then bind that value to each method, it will work. Unfortunately it does [not seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756294/how-to-pass-an-instance-variable-into-typescript-decorator-arguments) to pass `this` directly to the decorator, though that would be much cleaner.

```
const someObject: object = new Object();
class Main {
  private num = 42;

  constructor(other: Other) {
    other.init(someObject, this);
  }

  @Method(someObject)
  myMethod() {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log(this.num); // 42
  }
}

class Other {
  private methods: Record<string, Function> = {};

  init(obj: object, thisArg: object) {
    this.methods = Reflect.getMetadata(METHODS, obj);
    Object.keys(this.methods).forEach((method) => {
      this.methods[method] = this.methods[method].bind(thisArg);
    })
  }

  trigger(methodName: string) {
    this.methods[methodName]();
  }
}

const other = new Other();
new Main(other);
other.trigger("myMethod");
```

Comment: This is certainly not beatiful, but it works! I'll wait a few days if someone comes up with a better approach tough :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're returning a `function` instead of an arrow function on this line:

```
return function MethodDecorator(
```

This creates a new context (function scope), which causes `this` to point to the global object instead. `this` is defined: it is `this.num` that is undefined, since `window.num` does not exist.

Thereofre, if you return the function as an arrow function, the lexical `this` will be preserved and you will have access to `this.num`:

```
const Method = (obj: object) => {
  return (
    target: object,
    methodName: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) => {
    const metadata = Reflect.getMetadata(METHODS, obj);

    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      METHODS,
      { ...metadata, [methodName]: descriptor.value },
      obj
    );
  };
};
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But I think there is something else wrong (I've tried your solution and `this` is still undefined)