# Can't pull sqs queue name from .env file in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, amazon-sqs

When pulling the queue name through .env file I get the following error on the console:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'meta').

How can I pass queue name from .env file to nestjs @SqsMessageHandler decorator?. I am using @ssut/nestjs-sqs library.

```
 @SqsMessageHandler(process.env.QUEUE_NAME, false)
       public async handleMessage(message: AWS.SQS.Message) {
        console.log(message);
       }
    
       @SqsConsumerEventHandler(process.env.QUEUE_NAME,'processing_error',
       )
       public onProcessingError(error: Error, message: AWS.SQS.Message) {
        // report errors here
        console.error(error);
        console.error(message);
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that `process.env.QUEUE_NAME` is defined at that time? If you hard code its value there, it works?

Comment: you probably cant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756294/how-to-pass-an-instance-variable-into-typescript-decorator-arguments

Comment: @MicaelLevi if i hard code queue name, it works. but i want to use it from env file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `process.env.QUEUE_NAME` is not available at the time you're using it. You'll need invoke `dotenv` (or whatever package that read & parse the env file) by yourself if you want to use `process.env.` like this.

Comment: I have added these two lines in the main.ts file but it didn't work for me.
    import { config } from 'dotenv';
    config();
Could you please provide me a sample how to make .env variables inject into decorator.?

Comment: you just to load dotenv, like their docs shows. That's it. Try moving this `config()` to the file that uses the `process.env.` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
imports: [
    ...
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }),
  ],
```

> You can add env file import like this in your Sqs module, which is >the standard way of using .env files in a NestJS module.

I realized later that this doesn't work for registering the queue, or for the decorators. We ran into the same issue, the env vars are available inside the modules but not during build, and nest ignores

Depending on how you start your services you do these:

#### NPM Scripts

Inside your package.json add the env vars:

```
"start:dev": "QUEUE_NAME=your_queue_name nest start --watch"
```

#### Docker

Add your env var before the node build step inside your `Dockerfile`.

`ENV QUEUE_NAME your_queue_name`