# Constructor Spreads with Decorators in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, decorator

Getting some errors when i try to use constructor spreads with decorators in typescript, so given:

`export function httpGet(path?: string, ...middlewares : Function[]) { };`

and is used like:

```
class Controller {
  @httpGet('/:id')
  async get(ctx: Context) { .... }
}
```

which throws ....

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

30   @httpGet('/:id')
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/api/Controller.ts(30,3): error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature
of method decorator when called as an expression.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator) the method decorator signature:

```
export function httpGet(path?: string, ...middlewares : Function[]) {
    return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {
        // code goes here
    };  
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got it to compile but now I get runtime errors: https://gist.github.com/amcdnl/c3d43b4d52acedbdf6f1

Comment: @amcdnl change the target when compiling to ES5.

Comment: I'm targeting Node 5.5 with this proj and compiling to ES6.

Comment: @amcdnl are you running it with the `--harmony` flag? ([Read more](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) -- rest parameters)