# Typescript decorator confusion

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I've been playing with TypeScript decorators but just having no luck getting them working. I read [How to implement a typescript decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator) and also http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript from which I created the decorator implementation

```
function log(target: any, key: string, descriptor?: any) {

  // save a reference to the original method
  // this way we keep the values currently in the 
  // descriptor and don't overwrite what another 
  // decorator might have done to the descriptor.
  if(descriptor === undefined) {
      descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
  }
  var originalMethod = descriptor.value; 

  //editing the descriptor/value parameter
  descriptor.value =  function (...args: any[]) {
      var a = args.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join();
      // note usage of originalMethod here
      var result = 12;//originalMethod.apply(this, args);
      var r = JSON.stringify(result);
      console.log(`Call: ${key}(${a}) => ${r}`);
      return result;
  }

  // return edited descriptor as opposed to overwriting 
  // the descriptor by returning a new descriptor
  return descriptor;
}

class C {
    constructor(){
        console.log("built");
    }
    @log
    public foo(n: number) {
        console.log("foo called");
        return n * 2;
    }
}
//new MethodDecoratorExample().method("hi");
var c = new C();
var r = c.foo(23); //  "Call: foo(23) => 12"
console.log(r);
```

However running this code doesn't yield what I expect, in fact it doesn't seem to override the descriptor. Digging in more I find that in the generated code the call to `__decorate` has only three parameters

```
__decorate([
    log
], C.prototype, "foo");
```

This means that in __decorate c = 3 as the descriptor is not passed in. As a result the new descriptor isn't returned and the code flow progresses as if the method hasn't been intercepted.

So I must be applying this decorator incorrectly but I can't see how I'm doing it wrong. Is it perhaps being interpreted as a property descriptor? I did see some comment about that somewhere but that was in relation to defining the foo method in C as a lambda which I'm not doing.

How can I get this working?

Comment: The TypeScript Playground generates `__decorate([log], C.prototype, "foo", null);` for your code. What compiler options are you using?

Comment: I'm compiling with `tsc --experimentalDecorators decorator.ts` no .tsconfig file. I'm using 1.8 beta but I've also tried 1.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that TypeScript will generate ES3 code by default, and method [decorators generated for ES3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4741) apparently work somewhat differently than the ones generated for ES5. So, unless you actually need to target ES3 the simple way to fix your problem is to target ES5 with `tsc --experimentalDecorators --target es5`, or ES6 with `tsc --experimentalDecorators --target es6`.