# Is there an analogue of mvc action filters in typescript with node

Tags: node.js, typescript

In aspnet mvc we can do such concept called [action filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetUsers()
{}
```

So when `GetUsers()` gets hit the `Authorize` action occurs first and based on its logic `GetUsers()` even wont get executed if user is not authorized.

I am writing my node server code with typescript and I know there is such concept in typescript called decorators which is used in Angular2 but I am not sure if it is applies to node too.

Currently In node I have my `handlers/filters` declared in separate `.ts` file
And here is how I using them in my `app.ts`

```
import * as RequestHandlers from './infrastructure/handlers/requesthandlers';

app.use('/users', RequestHandlers.Authorize, users);
```

It is sort of OK but I just wondering if it is possible to do something like:

```
@whatewer { RequestHandlers.Authorize };
app.use('/users', users);
```

So `RequestHandlers.Authorize` gets executed before `app.use('/users', users);`

May be some one have any ideas?

Comment: You should look into Typescript decorators - they're a little fiddly to set up, but they might be able to do what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is sort of OK but I just wondering if it is possible to do something like

No. The decorator syntax is just a sugar over a function wrapper can only be used on *variables,functions,classes etc*. You cannot decorate an arbitrary statement.