# TypeScript custom decorator on model

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class as follows:

```
class Person {
   @indexField
   id : number;
   name : string;
}
```

Now I want to implement a method (nevermind design, just an example) - that will allow me to dynamically get the index field.

So,

```
    class Person {
       @indexField
       id : number;
       name : string;

       public function getIndex(){
          //Find which property is marked with "@indexField" and dynamically return value.
       }
   }
```

The examples left me a bit confused: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#decorators

What would be the approach, something like this in the model?

```
function indexField(target, key, descriptor) {
    getObjectInstanceSomehow().setIndexerField(key); //?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this way?

```
function indexField(target, propertyKey) {

    console.log("Index property is: ", propertyKey);
    target.indexKey = propertyKey
}

class Person {
    @indexField
    id:number;
    name:string;

    getIndex() {
        return this['indexKey'];
    }
}

let p = new Person();
console.log(p.getIndex()); // prints "id"
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20indexField(target%2C%20propertyKey)%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Index%20property%20is%3A%20%22%2C%20propertyKey)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20target.indexKey%20%3D%20propertyKey%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Person%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40indexField%0A%20%20%20%20id%3Anumber%3B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3Astring%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getIndex()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%5B'indexKey'%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20p%20%3D%20new%20Person()%3B%0Aconsole.log(p.getIndex())%3B%20%2F%2F%20prints%20%22id%22)]

It's just an example. You can store the index `propertyKey` however you want.

Resources:

- [How to implement a typescript decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator) - great summary how to write decorators in TypeScript