# What does the "@" char mean in ecmascript 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

Given the script below, that can be found in the [angular 2 official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html), what does the "@" character mean? Is it an ecmascript 6 feature?

Can anyone elaborate about it?

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  public hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

Comment: @ is used to indicate decorator and anotation before there mentioning name

Comment: See also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just TypeScript decorators, check them out [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

> A Class Decorator is declared just before a class declaration. The
>   class decorator is applied to the constructor of the class and can be
>   used to observe, modify, or replace a class definition. A class
>   decorator cannot be used in a declaration file, or in any other
>   ambient context (such as on a declare class).
>
> The expression for the class decorator will be called as a function at
>   runtime, with the constructor of the decorated class as its only
>   argument.
>
> If the class decorator returns a value, it will replace the class
>   declaration with the provided constructor function.
>
> NOTE  Should you chose to return a new constructor function, you must
>   take care to maintain the original prototype. The logic that applies
>   decorators at runtime will not do this for you. The following is an
>   example of a class decorator (@sealed) applied to the Greeter class:

```
@sealed
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```