# Will static javascript function using only constants be compiled to constant

Tags: javascript, performance, compilation, typescript

Will the following javascript

```
var StaticTest_A = (function () {
  function StaticTest_A() {
  }
  StaticTest_A.GetConstant = function () {
    return StaticTest_B.MyNumber + StaticTest_B.MyNumber;
  };
  return StaticTest_A;
})();
var StaticTest_B = (function () {
  function StaticTest_B() {
}
StaticTest_B.MyNumber = 5;
  return StaticTest_B;
})();
```

generated from this TypeScript

```
class StaticTest_A
{
   static GetConstant():number
   {
       return StaticTest_B.MyNumber + StaticTest_B.MyNumber;
   }
}

class StaticTest_B
{
   static MyNumber = 5;
}
```

be compiled so `StaticTest_A.GetConstant()` returns a constant or will the function be calculated on every call?

Comment: Nothing in JavaScript can guarantee that `StaticTest_B.MyNumber` won't be changed, so the function has to be re-evaluated.

Comment: Just add an `alert` or something and you will see the code runs again for each call, it's not cached.

Comment: See your points.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that expression will run each time and it should because `StaticTests_B.MyNumber` could change in the meantime, as Pointy pointed out. Additionally, TypeScript doesn't change the code you write to improve the performance—that's actually a [non-goal of the compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals).

If you only want the calculation to happen once for performance reasons then you will have to come up with your own solution to that. For example, you could create a reusable [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator/) that caches the value the first time it's run and then returns the cached value afterwards. You could then use that decorator anywhere you like:

```
function methodMemoize(target: Function | Object, key: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<() => any>) {
    const originalValue = descriptor.value;
    let hasRun = false;
    let returnedValue: any;

    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
        if (!hasRun) {
            returnedValue = originalValue.apply(this, args);
            hasRun = true;
        }

        return returnedValue;
    };
}

class StaticTest_A
{
    @methodMemoize
    static GetConstant()
    {
        console.log("run only once");
        return StaticTest_B.MyNumber + StaticTest_B.MyNumber;
    }
}

class StaticTest_B
{
   static MyNumber = 5;
}

StaticTest_A.GetConstant(); // "run only once", returns 10
StaticTest_A.GetConstant(); // returns cached 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution