# Angular 2 - Inject a dependency into a decorator factory

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular, decorator

Is there a way to inject a dependency into a decorator factory, using Angular's DI? Let's take the following code as a simplified example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-component',
  template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @PersonName()
  name: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(`Hello, ${this.name}`);
  }
}
```

Here, the intended behaviour of the `PersonName` decorator is for it to access a `Person` dependency, and use it to set the `name` property of the class.

Is it possible at all to implement the `PersonName` decorator for the code above?

Comment: Do you want to set the value for `name` from within `@PersonName()` decorator?

Comment: Yes - that's right.

Answer (score 9):

Currently, to inject dependencies into my decorators (and other extra module classes) I'm using this workaround:

```
import {Injectable, Injector} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class ExtraModuleInjector {
  private static injector;

  public static get(token: any) {
    if (ExtraModuleInjector.injector) {
      return ExtraModuleInjector.injector.get(token);
    }
  }

  constructor(public injector: Injector) {
    ExtraModuleInjector.injector = injector;
  }
}
```

After being injected to root component, it allows to use static get method to get dependencies during runtime functions execution.
Still looking for better solution.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the code from your module definition didn't you? Something like adding `.then()` to the end in order to set the dependency values?

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit tricky to do this, because decorators are executed at build time, not at the runtime. When decorator is executed, there's no instance of the class.

Back in ng2.beta.10, I used this to get the data from service (don't think you can from component, but I could be wrong...):

```
// some-route.ts
@CanActivate((next, prev) => {
  let store: any = getSingleton(Store);
})

// injector.ts
import {Injector} from 'angular2/core'

let appInjectorRef: Injector;

export const appInjector = (injector?: Injector) => {
  if (injector)
    appInjectorRef = injector;
  return appInjectorRef;
}

export function getSingleton(token: any) {
  let injector: Injector = appInjector();
  return injector.get(token);
}
```

..to be honest, looking at this code now I have no ide how it works (; But I know it did back then. Not sure what's the status now, or if there were any breaking changes since beta.10 related to the **Injector** and **ApplicationRef**...

Comment: Some credit to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572 with Plunker example.

Comment: In ~2.0.0 appInjector() returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it in Angular 7 is:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { setInjector } from './service/inj.service';
@NgModule({..})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(i: Injector) {
    setInjector(i)
  }
}
```

**decorator.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

let injector: Injector;
export const setInjector = (i: Injector)=>{
  injector = i
}

export function mydecorator(arg:any){
  let service: SomeServiceWhichNeedsToBeInjected
  return (target, key, descriptor)=>{
    if(descriptor === undefined) {
      descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key)
    }
    var originalMethod = descriptor.value
    descriptor.value = function () {
      if(!loading){
        service= injector.get(SomeServiceWhichNeedsToBeInjected)
      }
      //do something with service
      return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments)
    }
    return descriptor;
  }
}
```

**other.service.ts**

```
@mydecorator('somearg')
decoratedmethod(arg1){
  //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Because of the timing in which property decorators are evaluated you'll probably want to use Observables.

Given this basic interface

```
export interface DIProvider {
    setInjector(instance: Injector): void;
    getInjector(): Observable<Injector>;
    construct<T>(injectable: ProviderToken<T>): Observable<T>;
}
```

A primitive implementation might look something like the following.

```
export class InjectorProvider implements DIProvider {
    protected static instance: DIProvider;
    protected static readonly injector$: Subject<Injector> = new ReplaySubject<Injector>(1);
    protected static readonly notNull = (injector: Injector): boolean => !!injector;

    private constructor() {}

    public static getInstance() {
        if(!InjectorProvider.instance) {
          InjectorProvider.instance = new InjectorProvider();
        }
        return InjectorProvider.instance; 
    }

    public setInjector(injector: Injector) {
       InjectorProvider.injectors$.next(injector);
    }
    
    public getInjector() {
       return InjectorProvider.injectors$.pipe(
           filter(InjectorProvider.notNull)
       );
    }

    public construct<T>(injectable: ProviderToken<T>): Observable<T> {
        return this.getInjector().pipe(map(injector) => injector.get<T>(injectable)));
    }
}
```

With this we can

- store an injector instance via `setInjector()`
- access the stored injector via `getInjector()`
- construct dependencies with the injector via `construct()`

Now that we've set up a way of storing an injector and accessing it.
We need to find ourselves an injector.

---

Angular exposes the root injector in the `app.module.ts`
So let grab it.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({...})
export class AppModule {
    // get the root injector
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        InjectorProvider.getInstance().setInjector(injector);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Now that we have an instance of the root injector,
we can start constructing dependencies that the root injectors knows about.

---

```
 const provider: DIProvider = InjectorProvider.getInstance();

 provider.construct(PersonService).subscribe(console.log);

 provider.construct(AuthService).subscribe(console.log);
 
 provider.construct(LoggerService).subscribe(console.log);
 
 provider.construct(WebSocketService).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score -4):

You can do following:

```
export class AnnotationExample {
  @PersonName
  name: string;

  constructor() {
    alert(this.name);
  }
}

function PersonName(/*target: Function, fnName: string, fn: any*/) {
  return {value: 'amit'};
}

var whatIs = new AnnotationExample();
```

Comment: The question is about how one would go about injecting a service into a decorator. Not how to use a decorator. Specifically, they would like to access a `Person` dependency inside the decorator and then set the value of the decorated property `name` in the `HelloComponent`.