# What is meaning by @ symbol in typescript --Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using typescript for angular 2 application development.

But when we write code for component or route config or some other place
we use "@" symbol.

My question is what this symbol means and why it is required?

Answer (score 41):

The `@` symbol you are referring to is called `decorator`.

> Decorators provide a way to add both annotations and a meta-programming syntax for class declarations and members.

Basically when you are doing `@component` you are telling compiler that the class is a angular2 component with the metadata passed as an argument.

for eg.

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'heroes-app',
  templateUrl: 'heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['heroes.component.css'],  
})
class HeroesComponent{}
```

this code will tell compiler that class HeroesComponent is supposed to be an angular2 component with metadata passed as arguments and it will create a component class.

**Decorator isn’t a magic. It’s just function-calling.**

for eg.

```
@Component({
selector: 'static-component',
template: `<p>Static Component</p>`
})
class StaticComponent {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
class DynamicComponent {
}

const dynamicComponent = Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-component',
    template: `<p>Dynamic Component</p>`
})(DynamicComponent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: About your "is equivalent example": Are you saying that the decoration really turns "static" into "dynamic" or is this just an inconsistency in the example?

Comment: @bluenote10 its just naming mistake from my part

Answer (score 13):

This means you are applying a decorator.

> With the introduction of Classes in TypeScript and ES6, there now exist certain scenarios that require additional features to support annotating or modifying classes and class members. Decorators provide a way to add both annotations and a meta-programming syntax for class declarations and members. Decorators are a stage 1 proposal for JavaScript and are available as an experimental feature of TypeScript.

- [How to implement a typescript decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator)
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: I have read reference links provided by @Gunter and found as its nothing but just some CODE which get injected in actual CODE at runtime....but to inject it we use name of function preceded with @ symbol so Typescript understand that it is decorator and it should be take care while transpelling or later on.

Plz correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Decorators can be interpreted statically (without actually running the code) Angular uses this to generate code at build time (offline template compiler) and for tooling support like autocompletion in templates (both work in progress).

Comment: Taking advantage of this question... why have they decided to put '@' signs on their npm packages aswell?? import "@angular/core" and etc ...

Comment: As far as I know this is an NPM feature and creates a reserved namespace where only the Angular team can publish packages to.