# what is decorators in typescript, Why it is used? need real time example using typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator

What are "decorators" in TypeScript?  Why are they used?  What is the purpose of `@` symbol?  What would happen if we apply decorators?

I can't get clear idea after googling it also.

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is meaning by @ symbol in typescipt --Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170004/what-is-meaning-by-symbol-in-typescipt-angular-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorators are simply functions that modify (add functionality to) a class, property, method, or method parameter. The syntax is an “@” symbol followed by a function.

You could for example create a @readonly decorator to prevent modification of a class (that is preventing fields to be added or removed)

This is one of many articles describing that process:

https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/10/20/typescript-decorators/

This is also a rather good video on typescript decorators:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05FC8Wh7C5w