# What is the purpose of the "@" symbol in Javascript classes?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, class-properties

In [this example](https://adonisjs.com/adonisjs-at-a-glance) on AdonisJS, the Post class definition includes @column sections.  Can someone explain what this does?  I assume it's creating multiple instances of the 'column' class within the Post class as member variables, each instance having a different name and data type. But how does this work and what is the @ symbol for?

```
  import { column, BaseModel } from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm'

  export default class Post extends BaseModel {
    @column({ isPrimary: true })
    public id: number

    @column()
    public title: string

    @column()
    public description: string
  }
```

Would the following be equivalent (without the defined data types)?

```
export default class Post extends BaseModel
{
   constructor()
   {
      this.id = new column({ isPrimary: true });
      this.title = new column();
      this description = new column();
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After realizing AdonisJS is written in TypeScript, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170004/what-is-meaning-by-symbol-in-typescript-angular-2/38171230), which answers the question.

Comment: `@` usually refers to "decorators", currently a [Stage 2 Proposal for ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called "decorators", a proposed javascript feature.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

The proposal has gone through several iterations already. [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) and [babel](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) both have their own implementations of decorators.

Decorators can modify whole classes or class fields, e.g. by calling Object.defineProperty(classPrototype, key, {...}).

What exactly the decorator does is dependent on it's implementing function.