# Confusion about when decorators are called in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, decorator

I have been under the impression that decorators in TypeScript are called after the constructor of a class. However, I was told otherwise, for instance, the top answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator) post claims that *Decorators are called when the class is declared—not when an object is instantiated*. A Udemy instructor of an Angular course I was enrolled in also told me that decorators in Typescript run *before* property initialization.

However, my experiments on this subject seem to indicate otherwise. For instance, this is a simple Angular code with property binding:

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: '{{testString}}'  
})
export class TestComponent{    
  @Input() testString:string ="default string";    
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.testString);
   }       
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-test testString="altered string"></app-test>
```

When I execute the code, the console logs "default string" instead of "altered string". This proves that decorators are called after the constructor of a class executes.

Can somebody give me a definite answer of when decorators are called? Because my research online are contradicting the experiments I make. Thank you!

Comment: The post you link to is pretty exhaustive and it states clearly "Decorators are called when the class is declared—not when an object is instantiated." This is so. You can get behavior  on the instance by replacing either a method or the class (class and methods decorators can do that) but that is specific t the decorator implementation. The decorator itself runs at class delcaration

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Decorators are called when the class is declared—not when an object is
>   instantiated.

That's correct.

As @H.B. has already said, we can prove it by looking at the transpiled code.

```
var TestComponent = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TestComponent() {
        this.testString = "default string";
        console.log(this.testString);
    }
    __decorate([
        core_1.Input(),
        __metadata("design:type", String)
    ], TestComponent.prototype, "testString", void 0);
    TestComponent = __decorate([
        core_1.Component({
            selector: 'app-test',
            template: '{{testString}}'
        }),
        __metadata("design:paramtypes", [])
    ], TestComponent);
    return TestComponent;
}());
```

Now, let's go through the next steps to understand where you was wrong.

### Step 1. The main purpose is to provide metadata

> When I execute the code, the console logs "default string" instead of
>   "altered string". This proves that decorators are called after the
>   constructor of a class executes.

**You can't be sure until you know what `@Input()` decorator does**.

Angular `@Input` decorator just **adorns** component property with some information.

It's just metadata, that will be [stored](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7b7757dd3d38a95ed20a6dd2d6db44f269eec087/packages/core/src/util/decorators.ts#L129-L151) in `TestComponent.__prop__metadata__` property.

```
Object.defineProperty(constructor, PROP_METADATA, {value: {}})[PROP_METADATA]
```

[image]

### Step 2. Angular compiler.

Now its time when angular compiler collects all information about component including `@Input` metadatas to produce component factory. Prepared metadata looks like:

```
{
  "selector": "app-test",
  "changeDetection": 1,
  "inputs": [
    "testString"
  ],
  ...
  "outputs": [],
  "host": {},
  "queries": {},
  "template": "{{testString}}"
}
```

(*Note:* When Angular [TemplateParser](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7b7757dd3d38a95ed20a6dd2d6db44f269eec087/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L86) walk through template it uses this metadata [to check](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L628) whether directive has input with name `testString`)

Based on the metadata compiler [constructs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7b7757dd3d38a95ed20a6dd2d6db44f269eec087/packages/compiler/src/view_compiler/view_compiler.ts#L546-L555) updateDirective expressions:

```
if (dirAst.inputs.length || (flags & (NodeFlags.DoCheck | NodeFlags.OnInit)) > 0) {
  updateDirectiveExpressions =
      dirAst.inputs.map((input, bindingIndex) => this._preprocessUpdateExpression({
        nodeIndex,
        bindingIndex,
        sourceSpan: input.sourceSpan,
        context: COMP_VAR,
        value: input.value
      }));
}
```

that will be included in producing factory:

[image]

We can notice above that update expressions are generated in parent view(AppComponent).

### Step 3. Change detection

After angular produced all factories and inititialized all necessary objects it runs change detection cycly from top view through all child view.

During this process angular calls [checkAndUpdateView](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7b7757dd3d38a95ed20a6dd2d6db44f269eec087/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L350) function, where it also calls [updateDirectiveFn](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7b7757dd3d38a95ed20a6dd2d6db44f269eec087/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L359):

```
export function checkAndUpdateView(view: ViewData) {
  if (view.state & ViewState.BeforeFirstCheck) {
    view.state &= ~ViewState.BeforeFirstCheck;
    view.state |= ViewState.FirstCheck;
  } else {
    view.state &= ~ViewState.FirstCheck;
  }
  shiftInitState(view, ViewState.InitState_BeforeInit, ViewState.InitState_CallingOnInit);
  markProjectedViewsForCheck(view);
  Services.updateDirectives(view, CheckType.CheckAndUpdate);  <====
```

That's the first place where your `@Input` property [gets value](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/235a235fab45b2c82f8758fc9c0779f62a5b6c04/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L443):

```
providerData.instance[propName] = value;
if (def.flags & NodeFlags.OnChanges) {
  changes = changes || {};
  const oldValue = WrappedValue.unwrap(view.oldValues[def.bindingIndex + bindingIdx]);
  const binding = def.bindings[bindingIdx];
  changes[binding.nonMinifiedName !] =
    new SimpleChange(oldValue, value, (view.state & ViewState.FirstCheck) !== 0);
}
```

As you can see It happens before `ngOnChanges` hook.

### Conclusion

Angular doesn't update `@Input` property value during decorator execution. Change detection mechanism is responsible for such things.

Answer (score 3):

The reason of your confusion is not caused by how Decorators works, but how Angular updates it's input-bound properties. You can prove yourself and

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.testString) // see updated value
}
```

This happens because `ngOnInit` is called after the first `ngOnChanges` and `ngOnChanges` updates your input.

Comment: So decorators are called with class declaration in Typescript, but the input-binding behavior in Angular is only first executed in the first ngOnChanges, which is called after the constructor. Is this correct?

Comment: @Eddie Lin - Yes, decorator is just a function attached to either class, method, accessor or property (as in your case). That function can behave as you want, so Angular wrote `@Input` decorator that changes target property value depending of the result NgOnChanges. I am playing arround now with it, but cant find proves yet so I could demonstrate, but I am pretty sure that `@Input` is being evaluated on constructor level, but gets called depending on ngOnChanges

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at the generated code, e.g.

```
const defaultValue = (value: any) =>
  (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    target[propertyKey] = value;
  };

class Test
{
  @defaultValue("steven")
  myProperty: string;

  constructor()
  {
    console.log(this.myProperty);
  }
}

new Test();
```

Will produce this:

```js
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var defaultValue = function (value) {
    return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
        target[propertyKey] = value;
    };
};
var Test = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Test() {
        console.log(this.myProperty);
    }
    __decorate([
        defaultValue("steven")
    ], Test.prototype, "myProperty", void 0);
    return Test;
}());
new Test();
```

As you an see the `__decorate` function is called on the property at *class declaration time*. This redefines the property according to the decorator code. For Angular this probably just sets some metadata, priming the class for inputs. Here it directly sets the value.

Thus, here the property will already have changed in the constructor.