# How to use angular 6 class decorator in a component?

Tags: typescript, angular6

I create a component in angular 6 with sample on how to implement decorators.
So, I create a custom decorator called @Course and set a value there, named Angular 6. Now, how to get that value in my component's constructor?

I want to log the "Angular 6" value to my constructor. How's that possible?

Here is my code. Work's fine. I've got the value. But got an error in command line

`ERROR in src/app/components/decorators/decorators.component.ts(19,22): error TS2339: Property
'course' does not exist on type 'DecoratorsComponent'.`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

function Course(target) {
  Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, 'course', {
    value: () => "Angular 6"
  })
}

@Course
@Component({
  selector: 'app-decorators',
  templateUrl: './decorators.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./decorators.component.scss']
})
export class DecoratorsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.course());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what decorators are and how they work in conjunction with the type(s) they decorated on. Can you provide a link to the tutorial you mentioned?

Comment: How do I implement decorators the right way? I don't have tutorial link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a typescript decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator)

Answer (score 0):

target.prototype.course = () => 'Angular 6';

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell TypeScript compilier about dynamically added property. [The simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441178/3793592):

```
@Course
// ...
export class DecoratorsComponent implements OnInit {
    // ... 
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

Alternatively, you read the dynamic property as "array item":

```
constructor() {

    const courseProp = this['course'];

    if (courseProp) {
        console.log(courseProp());
    }
}
```

NOTE: it is good practice to check existence of the property, because decorator may be removed.

Comment: While this works, it feels like a major failing of TypeScript. The first answer allows anything, the second means there is no compile-time checking (or IntelliSense). Is there really no better way?