# TypeScript decorator reports "Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression"

Tags: typescript

```
@xxx("xxx")
class A{
    msg:string
    constructor(msg:string) {
        this.msg = msg
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.msg)
    }
}

function xxx(arg:string) {
    function f(target) {
        function ff(msg: string) {
            return new target(arg + ":" + msg)
        }
        return ff
    }
    return f
}

let a = new A("hellow")
a.print()
```

When compile, it reports:

> decorator.ts(1,1): error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
> Type '(msg: string) => any' is not assignable to type 'void'.

But the genrated js executed well. I don't know why it reports an error.

Comment: also make sure you call `@Input()` with parenthesis `()` since its a function.

Comment: As STEEL suggested,,, This is usually the reason you get an error.

Comment: Also note that decorators don't work on arrow functions (for function decorators). () =>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The compiler expects your decorator to either be void or return a value that is compatible with A. It sees that you return a `(msg:any) => any` but can not draw the conclusion that this function is compatible with A.

If you want to get rid of the error, you can cast the ff to any when you return it, or maybe even to `typeof A` to communicate the intention clearer:

```
function xxx(arg: string)
{
    function f(target)
    {
        function ff(msg: string)
        {
            return new target(arg + ":" + msg)
        }
        return <typeof A><any>ff
    }
    return f
}
```

That said, it's probably not a good idea to replace classes like this, you should at least maintain the constructor:

[TypeScript documentation:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

> NOTE  Should you chose to return a new constructor function, you must
>   take care to maintain the original prototype. The logic that applies
>   decorators at runtime will not do this for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. The casting technique was exactly what I needed. I didn't need to double cast with <any>, <typeof A> was sufficient. Would upvote you twice if I could.

Comment: How do you do this in a generic way?  If I have to cast to the class I place the decorator on how do I cast to the type that the decorator was placed without hard coding the type?

Comment: @chubbsondubs I have wanted to do this as well, but I don't think I found any solution back then. Maybe we have some new syntax now, I don't know. I think one of the problem is that the type of the constructor of a class has no type reference to the type of the class: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841

Comment: So I read the decorators proposal and there is an example in there that doesn't return anything hence doesn't replace the constructor.  That would enable class level decorators that can take parameters using the factory decorator pattern.  But only if you don't want to replace the constructor.

Comment: It's definitely a huge hole in the proposal though, and probably why Angular 2 still uses their annotation model as opposed to adopting decorators.

Answer (score 39):

My issue was that I still had `"experimentalDecorators": true` in the `compilerOptions` of my tsconfig.json, but that's not needed in the most recent version of TypeScript anymore.

Comment: And I had to remove them (includes `emitDecoratorMetadata`) and add them again, so vs code picked them up after a typescript update...

Comment: In my case, I had to close all the files in which the error appeared, edit the tsconfig
and reopen them.

Comment: Wow. They must really be experimental. I just had to uncomment the code, (i.e. enable) and the errors went away.

Answer (score 14):

This appears to be resolved by adding ES2016 or ES5 as the target in tsconfig.json

https://github.com/alsatian-test/alsatian/issues/344#issuecomment-290418311

Answer (score 10):

On Vue+Vite it requires adding:

```
"target": "ES5",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true
```

to tsconfig.**app**.json, not to tsconfig.json.

Comment: `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,` is missing in other answers.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem and found that I was selecting the src folder in VS Code instead of the project folder. Once I selected the project folder as the root directory, the tsconfig.json file was recognized and the error disappeared.

Comment: Great answer man! You save me a lot of time

Comment: I had similar issue, but the only difference was that I had `/workspace/tsconfig.json` correct with `experimentalDecorators`, but in a `/workspaces/projectA/tsconfig.json` I didn't have `experimentalDecorators`

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that must have been facing this issue in 2022. It took me a long time but I realized that I was using an arrow functions. Decorators will not work on arrow functions. When I changed it, it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 6):

I got similar error message:

> Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
> The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1.ts(1238)

My Typescript version is `5.0.4`.I resolved this problem by adding this to tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true, // the key line
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my instance it was just Visual Studio Code that showed the error message after adding new modules for an `Angular` project via `ng g m <module-name>`.

When I couldn't figure out what's wrong with the code, I used the universally valid IT wisdom, closed Visual Studio Code and reopened it - the errors were gone.

Comment: thanks, I was in the same situation and was sure none of the other solutions weren't my case. unfortunate it didn't hit me to restart vscode :D

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Alex above, the compiler expects your decorator to either be void or return a value that is compatible with A. So you can cast the ff to `typeof target`.

```
function xxx(arg:string) {
    function f(target) {
        function ff(msg: string) {
            return new target(arg + ":" + msg)
        }
        return ff as typeof target
    }
    return f
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error message with additional message

> Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an
> expression.   The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments,
> but the decorator expects 1. ts(1238)

I am only using a single ts file to learn about decorators. So, typescript always throws error because nodejs runs only .js file. The solution is to create a js file using following command:

```
tsc --experimentalDecorators decorator.ts
```

it still shows error message in IDE but when run decorator.js file, file runs perfectly. So, ignore the error message in ts file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an error as below, just like the user codewithsg's error in previous answer:

> Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an
> expression. The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments,
> but the decorator expects 1. ts

You must know that since the version 5 of TypeScript, there's a required second parameter called “context”, which you should include in your decorator functions and set its type based on the goal of decorator. See this example and you can read more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#decorators).

```
function loggedMethod(originalMethod: any, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext) {
const methodName = String(context.name);

function replacementMethod(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
    console.log(`LOG: Entering method '${methodName}'.`)
    const result = originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
    console.log(`LOG: Exiting method '${methodName}'.`)
    return result;
}

return replacementMethod;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This may be the case of opening src folder in vscode instead of project folder.
You can verify it by looking at the top of vscode.

[vscode example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJnup.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35310740)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this kind of error in angular service with @Injectable() decorator then check after you inject that service into any respective component where you want to use that service. The error should vanish after the inject into any component.

Answer (score 0):

I added my file name to tsconfig

```
"files": [
    "./Basics/index.ts",
    "./System Design/Creational/SingletonPattern.ts"
]
```

also added these

```
"target": "ES5",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true
```

Comment: Answer needs more elaboration and supporting details.