# I need a help on Angular once i runned the application keep showing an error saying that :

Tags: angular

Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
Argument of type 'ClassDecoratorContext' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol | undefined'.

I expected the application should not display an error
because it runs well but keep showing this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446480/typescript-decorator-reports-unable-to-resolve-signature-of-class-decorator-whe ?