# Using JSON.stringify in conjunction with TypeScript getter/setter

Tags: json, typescript, getter-setter

I am using getter/setter accessors in TypeScript. As it is not possible to have the same name for a variable and method, I started to prefix the variable with a lower dash, as is done in many examples:

```
private _major: number;

get major(): number {
  return this._major;
}
set major(major: number) {
  this._major = major;
}
```

Now when I use the JSON.stringify() method to convert the object into a JSON string, it will use the variable name as the key: _major.

As I don't want the JSON file to have all keys prefixed with a lower dash, is there any possibility to make TypeScript use the name of the getter method, if available? Or are there any other ways to use the getter/setter methods but still produce a clean JSON output?

I know that there are ways to manually modify the JSON keys before they are written to the string output. I am curious if there is simpler solution though.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d7tndhh/1/) which demonstrates the current behaviour.

Comment: I Suppose another approach would be to use capitalisation of the properties, e.g. get Major()...  like the C# naming convention for properties

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't have `JSON.stringify` using the getter/setter name instead of the property name.

But you can do something like this:

```
class Version {
    private _major: number;

    get major(): number {
        return this._major;
    }

    set major(major: number) {
        this._major = major;
    }

    toJsonString(): string {
        let json = JSON.stringify(this);
        Object.keys(this).filter(key => key[0] === "_").forEach(key => {
            json = json.replace(key, key.substring(1));
        });

        return json;
    }
}

let version = new Version();
version.major = 2;
console.log(version.toJsonString()); // {"major":2}
```

Comment: With reference to the following answer, you could just have defined a toJSON function on your object which automatically gets used by JSON.stringify(yourclassobject)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705211/object-defineproperty-on-a-prototype-prevents-json-stringify-from-serializing-it

Comment: @N15M0_jk yeah, that's true, but I prefer not to "override" the behavior of `JSON.stringify` and instead just use `version.toJsonString()`

Comment: This produce error: TypeError: myObject.toJsonString is not a function

Comment: @TeodorKolev I just checked this exact code in the typescript playground and it worked great.

Comment: Use `toJSON`. For some reason, nobody uses `toJSON` or `valueOf` when they absolutely should. I guess not a lot of people know these exist. For instance, `class User {...}` could leverage the method `valueOf() { return this.id; }` so it can be used as `var id = +user;`. Not sure if that provides you with anymore leverage.

Answer (score 11):

based on @Jan-Aagaard solution I have tested this one

```
public toJSON(): string {
    let obj = Object.assign(this);
    let keys = Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype);
    obj.toJSON = undefined;
    return JSON.stringify(obj, keys);
}
```

in order to use the toJSON method

Comment: To get full object I used

 let keys = Object.keys(this).concat(Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype)) 

instead

Comment: This is the right answer. But I don't think you need the line `obj.toJSON = undefined;` as `JSON.stringify` ignores methods altogether. Please let me know if I'm incorrect.

Comment: @Cody Yes, it ignores methods on serializing, but if the `toJSON` method remains defined it will call it instead of serializing the object directly and this generates a recursive eternal loop. You need to "undefine" the `toJSON` to avoid that.

Answer (score 5):

I think iterating through the properties and string manipulating is dangerous. I would do using the prototype of the object itself, something like this:

```
public static toJSONString() : string {
    return JSON.stringify(this, Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype)); // this is version class
}
```

Comment: this is working, but it's only returning the setters and getters. how can I get all the other properties that are not getters and setters?

Answer (score 3):

I've written a small library [ts-typed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-typed), which generate getter/setter for runtime typing purpose. I've faced the same problem when using JSON.stringify(). So i've solved it by adding a kind of serializer, and proposing to implement a kind of toString (in Java) buy calling it toJSON.

Here is an example:

```
import { TypedSerializer } from 'ts-typed';

export class RuntimeTypedClass {
    private _major: number;

    get major(): number {
       return this._major;
    }

    set major(major: number) {
       this._major = major;
    }
    /**
    * toString equivalent, allows you to remove the _ prefix from props.
    *
    */
    toJSON(): RuntimeTypedClass {
        return TypedSerializer.serialize(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A new answer to an old question. For situations where there is no private field for a getter/setter, or where the private field name is different to the getter/setter, we can use the `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` to find the `get` methods from the prototype.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400835/2325676

We add the `toJSON` function here so that it works with `JSON.stringify` as mentioned by other posters. This means we can't call `JSON.stringify()` within `toJSON` as it will cause an infinite loop so we clone using `Object.assign(...)`

I also removed the `_private` fields as a tidyup measure. You may want to remove other fields you don't want to incude in the JSON.

```
public toJSON(): any {

    //Shallow clone
    let clone: any = Object.assign({}, this); 

    //Find the getter method descriptors
    //Get methods are on the prototype, not the instance
    const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))

    //Check to see if each descriptior is a get method
    Object.keys(descriptors).forEach(key => {
        if (descriptors[key] && descriptors[key].get) {

            //Copy the result of each getter method onto the clone as a field
            delete clone[key];
            clone[key] = this[key]; //Call the getter
        }
    });

    //Remove any left over private fields starting with '_'
    Object.keys(clone).forEach(key => {
        if (key.indexOf('_') == 0) {
            delete clone[key];
        }
    });

    //toJSON requires that we return an object
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: Using TypeScript 5.0.4 I have a compiler error at `clone[key] = this[key];`. The error is `error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AccountRecord'.` Don't know how to resolve this. `this` can't be casted so something else, though. In my this is an instance of a class named `AccountRecord` which doesn't have an indexer that takes a string.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't dynamic but it work

```
export class MyClass{
     text: string

     get html() {
         return this.text.toString().split("\n").map(e => `<p>${e}</p>`).join('');
     }

     toJson(): string {
         return JSON.stringify({ ...this, html: this.html })
     }
}
```

In calling

```
console.log(myClassObject.toJson())
```