# How to make JSON.stringify to only serialize TypeScript getters?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, getter

I have the following class structure:

```
export abstract class PersonBase {
    public toJSON(): string {
        let obj = Object.assign(this);
        let keys = Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype);
        obj.toJSON = undefined;
        return JSON.stringify(obj, keys);
    }
}

export class Person extends PersonBase {

    private readonly _firstName: string;
    private readonly _lastName: string;

    public constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._lastName = lastName;
    }

    public get first_name(): string {
        return this._firstName;
    }

    public get last_name(): string {
        return this._lastName;
    }
}

export class DetailPerson extends Person {

    private _address: string;

    public constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public get address(): string {
        return this._address;
    }
     
    public set address(addy: string) {
        this._address = addy;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get `toJSON` to output all the getters (excluding private properties) from the full object hierarchy.

So if I have a `DetailPerson` instance and I call the `toJSON` method, I want to see the following output:

```
{
   "address": "Some Address",
   "first_name": "My first name",
   "last_name": "My last name"
}
```

I used one of the solutions from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080473/using-json-stringify-in-conjunction-with-typescript-getter-setter) but it doesn't solve my particular use case - I am not getting all the getters in the output.

What do I need to change here to get the result I am looking for?

Comment: Have you defined the method `toJsonString` on both the `Person` and `DetailPerson` classes, as shown in the post you linked? I don't see them defined in the code you posted.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the exact issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: Amendments made.

Comment: @Daz Maybe you'd like to edit this question again? As far as I can tell, the `toJSON` method added to `PersonBase` doesn't return the getters from `DetailPerson`. Also, the previous phrasing of the question made it more clear that you want to omit "private" properties (i.e. you only want getters).

Comment: Additional edits made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you provided uses `Object.keys` which leaves out properties on the prototype.

You could use `for...in` instead of `Object.keys`:

```
public toJSON(): string {
    let obj: any = {};

    for (let key in this) {
        if (key[0] !== '_') {
            obj[key] = this[key];
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

**Edit:** This is my attempt to return only getters, recursively, without assuming that non-getters start with underscores. I'm sure there are gotchas I missed (circular references, issues with certain types), but it's a good start:

```
abstract class PersonBase {
  public toJSON(): string {
    return JSON.stringify(this._onlyGetters(this));
  }

  private _onlyGetters(obj: any): any {
    // Gotchas: types for which typeof returns "object"
    if (obj === null || obj instanceof Array || obj instanceof Date) {
      return obj;
    }

    let onlyGetters: any = {};

    // Iterate over each property for this object and its prototypes. We'll get each
    // property only once regardless of how many times it exists on parent prototypes.
    for (let key in obj) {
      let proto = obj;

      // Check getOwnPropertyDescriptor to see if the property is a getter. It will only
      // return the descriptor for properties on this object (not prototypes), so we have
      // to walk the prototype chain.
      while (proto) {
        let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, key);

        if (descriptor && descriptor.get) {
          // Access the getter on the original object (not proto), because while the getter
          // may be defined on proto, we want the property it gets to be the one from the
          // lowest level
          let val = obj[key];

          if (typeof val === 'object') {
            onlyGetters[key] = this._onlyGetters(val);
          } else {
            onlyGetters[key] = val;
          }

          proto = null;
        } else {
          proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
        }
      }
    }

    return onlyGetters;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... ideally i was hoping for a solution that was more generic, something that didn't make assumptions about how i name private properties vs getters\setters. In the case my private property is named firstName and the getter\setter is First_Name or any other variant this won't work. I should have been clearer with my question, apologies.

Comment: I edited my response. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: What would it take to modify this so that it would correctly serialize a get property that was in-fact another object I had defined? In the example above say the DetailPerson has a Pet object property with its own set of get\set properties?

Comment: @Daz I updated the answer over time to address that issue - does it not work?

Comment: Apologies, I did not see those changes, the updates have in fact resolved the issue, however, it is now not serializing Date properties properly, all i see is {}

Comment: @Daz I made an update, but can't test at the moment. Can you tell me if it works?

Comment: That did it, thank you. Appreciate the very quick replies.

Comment: I think you shouldn't do `JSON.stringify` inside the `toJSON` function, just output the object tree the way you want it to be formatted.

Comment: Unfortunately, both return just `{ }` in my case, i.e. an empty JSON object.

Comment: @Manfred Did you try to debug it and see why it happens in your case?

Comment: @FrankModica I debugged it and also tried a few other things but couldn't figure it out yet. For noww I put it into the "too hard" basket to revisit again in the future. As a temporary measure, I just implemented a `toJSON` method in which I define a JSON object with the values I need, then use `JSON.stringify(theObj)` to return a string. Not generic, not nice, but does the job at least for the one class where I need it.