# How to convert a TypeScript class instance with getter/setter to JSON to store in MySQL database

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following TypeScript class that contains a getter / setter:

```
export class KitSection {

    uid: string;
    order: number;

    set layout(layout: KitLayout) {
        this._layout = new KitLayout(layout);
    }

    get layout() {
        return this._layout;
    }

    private _layout: KitLayout;

    constructor(init?: Partial<KitSection>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }

}

// I can create an instance like so:
const section = new KitSection(data);
```

I need to `POST` this instance to my server as a JSON object to store in a MySQL database column of type: `JSON`, so I figured I could do the following:

```
const jsonSection = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(section))
```

This creates a `JSON` object, but when I inspect in the console, i see my private getter/setter variable instead of the public variable in the object:

```
console.log(jsonSection);

///IN CONSOLE///

uid: "a"
order: 0
_layout: {_rows: Array(2), columns: 12}
```

I don't want to store the private variable `_layout` in my database, I need to store the public counterpart defined in the getter/setter: `layout`.

Next, I checked out the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44237286/6480913 where it suggests to add the following method to convert to `JSON`:

```
public toJSON(): string {
    let obj = Object.assign(this);
    let keys = Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype);
    obj.toJSON = undefined;
    return JSON.stringify(obj, keys);
}
```

However, this returns an empty object. Upon inspection, when I `console.log()` the `this.constructor.prototype`, I see the all the properties of the object, but each object is kind of greyed out, so when we use `Object.keys()`, I receive an empty array. Why are these constructor properties greyed out?

Comment: I've discovered that the greyed out (aka dimmed) properties mean that they are not enumerable, which is why they don't show up in Object.keys, but why is that? The default is that these properties ARE enumerable, I didn't set them otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` will *only* iterate over own enumerable properties. Here, since `layout` is a property on the *prototype* object, not the instance itself, when you try to stringify the instance, the getter is not invoked. (but since the `_layout` *is* an own enumerable property, it *is* included in the result)

Similarly, the following stringified object is empty:

```js
const obj = Object.create({
  get prop() {
    return 'val';
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

You could fix it by putting the getter directly on the instance, and by making the `_layout` non-enumerable. This way, when stringified, the getter will be invoked, but `_layout` will not be included:

```
export class KitSection {

    uid: string;
    order: number;

    private _layout: KitLayout;

    constructor(init?: Partial<KitSection>) {
        Object.defineProperty(
            this,
            'layout',
            {
                enumerable: true,
                get() {
                    return this._layout;
                },
                set(newVal) {
                    this._layout = new KitLayout(newVal);
                }
            }
        );
        Object.defineProperty(
            this,
            '_layout',
            {
                enumerable: false,
                value: undefined,
            }
        );
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}

const section = new KitSection(data);
```

It'll look a bit clearer if you use private class field syntax instead:

```
export class KitSection {
    #layout: KitLayout | undefined;
    constructor(init?: Partial<KitSection>) {
        Object.defineProperty(
            this,
            'layout',
            {
                enumerable: true,
                get() {
                    return this.#layout;
                },
                set: (newVal) => {
                    this.#layout = new KitLayout(newVal);
                }
            }
        );
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

You could also invoke the getter manually.

If the `KitLayout` is essentially serializable, to turn the serialized object back into a KitSection instance, `KitLayout` or one of its helper methods needs to be able to turn a serialized `KitLayout` into an instance. Either pass it through the constructor again (just call `new KitSection`, which hands it to `KitLayout`), or separate the `layout` from the deserialized object and have a separate method on `KitSection` that calls `KitLayout`'s helper method and assigns the private property, maybe something like:

```
integrateLayout(layoutInfo) {
  this.#layout = KitLayout.makeKitLayoutFromLayoutInfo(layoutInfo)
}
```

where `layoutInfo` is the plain object.

Comment: thanks so far, a little confused though because even the `uid` and the `order` properties don't show up in `Object.keys` when I run the `toJSON` method, why is that?

Comment: They don't look to be assigned to the instance anywhere - they only exist in the Typescript annotations, as far as I can see

Comment: I suppose I have a fundamental misunderstanding of instances and prototypes (coming from C#), let me read up on some documentation and get back to this

Comment: alright took me this long to wrap my head around everything! I do believe there is a syntax ordering error in your last block of code, I think the `Object.assign()` needs to be run after the `defineProperty` in order to set the layout instance variable.

Comment: Are you intending for the `init` object to invoke the setter? If it just contains the `uid` and `order` properties, it shouldn't matter

Comment: yes, the object passed through is a partial of the KitSection which will contain a `layout` property